# Transferring domain from netfirms control panel to VPS server(netfirms)

Tags: domains

HI All,

I wanted to transfer a register domain from the control panel of the Netfirms to the VPS server of the Netfirms

Comment: That's nice. Now contact Netfirms to do that for you.

Comment: How is this got to do with programming? Maybe for Netfirms side, but not the user i suppose?

Comment: Thanks lot ... So,now i know that stack overflow is only for the programming related questions

Comment: Please contact Netfirms, their job is to help people with these issues.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a "domain transfer" technically. You're only changing from one hosting service (if any) to another. You should contact Netfirms, setup a VPS account and then point your domain's DNS to it.